# Excel Find value, then change a value next to it.

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Maybe it is my lack of technical jargon but I am struggling to find this answer. I am stuck on two problems I will handle one at a time.

Can I search for a value and if I do not find it add it to the end of my data set Without copy and pasting or typing every data set in.

Comment: You can do that with VBA but it will be tricky just using formulas.

Comment: Does your 'data set' contain just one column?

Comment: It can't be done with formulas. 
Assume column A has your existing data set with now blank rows in the middle. Cell B1 has your new data.
You can do so much with forumulas, but step 4 is where things come unglued.
[1] B2 =VLOOKUP(B1,A:A,1,false)
[2]  B3=MIN(IF(A:A="",ROW(A:A)) then hit CTRL SHIFT ENTER. It puts {} round formula.
[3] B4=ADDRESS(B3, 1)
[4] B5=IF(ISNA) to assign B1 to cell ref of B4. CAN'T do. Only the cell formula is in 'itself'. This means VBA is the only way to go.

Comment: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2495-excel-find-first-blank-cell.html#a2 - has VBA for the first blank row.. This will get you started.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but here's what I think:
You can use 
IFERROR(LOOKUP(value, column_or_row_where_value_is, ""), value)

Let me know if it doesn't work.

Regards